# Encrypting REST api payload and responses like any Google Service

Tags: rest, encryption

In Gmail console I've seen all the requests but can't find single request with mail content in plainTtext in it. Also I've noticed the same thing with `messages.google.com`.

What I've observed so far is that one REST call with some encryption key, may be that's used on browser side to decrypt REST responses.

The question

1. How to achieve encryption of responses and payloads like google messages/gmail.
2. If I can see that key in response then I can decrypt all other responses using that key, isn't it ? Then is it still secure or my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Are you talking about transport-level or document-level encryption? The primer one is done via TLS (HTTPS) and prevents from sniffing content over a connection. But once a document has reached its final destination the receiver can read it normally. The latter on requires that a client knows how to interpret the received bytes in order for it to convert it back to its original form. There are too many encryption/decryption algorithm out there to give detailed answers. One could be GPG en/decryption using a public/private key pair and so on

Comment: yes I'm talking about transport layer (via HTTPS). I guess then when client receives public key that's also safe unless that client machine is compromised.